# Existence of subgroups in group of order $2n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with order $2n$. Let's assume $G$ has $2$ distinct subgroups $G_1$ and $G_2$ both of order $n$.

I want to prove that there exists another subgroup $G_3$ of order $n$ with $G_3\neq G_1$ and $G_3 \neq G_2$.

Both $G_1$ and $G_2$ are normal since they have index 2. When I'm asked to prove the existence of a subgroup I immediately think of Sylow theorems, but I don't know if they are helpful here since by conjugating $G_1$ we would still obtain $G_1$. Hence $n$ cannot be prime.

Any hints?